# NotImplementedError: `create()` must be implemented in serializer.Serializer inheritance

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-3.7

I am getting error in creating auth token using serializer, I am Django beginner research lot and trying various ways to solve but it not solve, please anyone can help me in this.

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 169, in create
    raise NotImplementedError('`create()` must be implemented.')

NotImplementedError: `create()` must be implemented.

```
class CreateAuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Authentication serializer"""

    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password
        )

        if not user:
            msg = _('unable to authenticate with username and password')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authentication')

        attrs['user'] = user
        return attrs
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you are using `serializers.Serializer`, it does not have a `create()` method built in unlike `serializers.ModelSerializer`. Probably you are trying to call `serializer.save()`, if you want to save an instance then you need to implement `create()` method. But probably you don't need it. More info:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Comment: Hi Rudra, I don't want `create()` method in `serializers.Serializer` I want just same like in this [https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a628a2dbce8f8f3047d30fe5345f86ae843bcdcc/rest_framework/authtoken/serializers.py#L7]

Comment: Then remove any code resembles serializers.save() from view, then it should be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for the user"""
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

Solved by using `ObtainAuthToken` inherited instead of `generics.CreateAPIView`

Answer (score 3):

check that whether you are using the right object,

for example, it's `ModelSerializer`, if I misuse `Serializer`, the NotImplemented will occur:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Product

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```